Azure B2C custom policies select the redirect URL during sign-up/sign-in
I'm using Azure B2C custom policies for sign-in/sing-up flows.
Before running Custom Policy I can choose ReplyUrl for redirection after sign-in/sign-up.
But my flow can create different types of user and each one should be redirected to a different site.
There are any way to override redirectURL during sign-up/sign-in flow in the custom policies XML?
(I'm using OpenIdConnect)
Resolve this redirection using js or another endpoint not working for me

As far as I am aware, there is no way to change the redirect URL during the authentication flow.
Maybe the application that the user gets redirected to needs to make this decision?
Apps often have a generic redirect page from which they get redirected to the appropriate location.
